# sql to LINQ with left join group by and sum() throws exception

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, left-join, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a query which I converted to LINQ expression. But throwing Null exception.

Objective: Payment Type can have three values (0,1,2).I need to query total sum amount for all currency for all three PaymentType. Also if the record for specific currency doesn't exist for either of three values of paymentType. Amount should display it as zero.

Table Structure:

```
      Currency varchar(10),
      PaymentType(int),
      amount(decimal)
```

Query:

```
     select aa.Currency,aa.PaymentType,sum(bb.amount) from (
     select * from (select distinct paymenttype from payment) a cross join                        
     (select distinct currency from payment) c
     ) aa left join payment bb on aa.PaymentType = bb.PaymentType and    
     aa.Currency = bb.Currency group by aa.PaymentType,aa.Currency
     order by aa.Currency
```

Linq Expression:

```
       var temp = _db.Payments.Select(c => c.PaymentType) .Distinct() 
      .SelectMany(c => _db.Payments.Select(a => a.Currency).Distinct(), 
      (PaymentType, Currency) => new { PaymentType, Currency }).ToList();


       var data = from p in temp join c in _db.Payments on new {                
       p.PaymentType, p.Currency } equals new { c.PaymentType, c.Currency }  
       into j1 from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty() group j2 by new { 
       p.PaymentType, p.Currency } into grouped select new { paymenttype = 
       grouped.Key.PaymentType, currency = grouped.Key.Currency, amount = 
       grouped.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.Amount ?? 0) };
```

But It is giving me "Object Reference" error due to NULL exception in SelectMany statement while declaring new.

```
         t => (decimal?)t.Amount ?? 0
```

Can someone help where i am doing wrong.

Comment: My best guess is that either p.PaymentType or p.Currency is NULL

Comment: @Ako Yes you are right. Let me explain u with a sample. say currency USD has values with paymenttype 0,1 but not with 2. Now my requirement is I need USD, 2 and sum of amount as 0. So i created a superset in my temp and then tried joining it. So now for USD ,2 there is no amount in table and hence null. Not sure how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten the code a bit with some sample data and reproduced the error as described.

```
var Payments = new [] {new {PaymentType = 0, Currency = "EUR", Amount = 10}, 
                              new {PaymentType = 0, Currency = "CHF", Amount = 70}, 
                              new {PaymentType = 2, Currency = "CHF", Amount = 80}, 
                              new {PaymentType = 1, Currency = "GBP", Amount = 90}, 
                              new {PaymentType = 1, Currency = "EUR", Amount = 100}};


        var temp = Payments.Select(c => c.PaymentType).Distinct()
                           .SelectMany(c => Payments.Select(a => a.Currency).Distinct(), 
                                                            (pt, cur) => new { PaymentType = pt, Currency = cur })
                           .ToList();


        var data = from p in temp
                   join c in Payments on new { p.PaymentType, p.Currency } equals new { c.PaymentType, c.Currency } into j1
                   from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group j2 by new
                   {
                       p.PaymentType,
                       p.Currency
                   } into grouped
                   select grouped;

        foreach (var g in data.ToList())
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", g.Key.PaymentType, g.Key.Currency, g.Sum(t => t.Amount));
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

So the problem was that t.amount is not null: t itself is null. So all you need to adjust is:

```
grouped.Sum(t => t == null ? 0 : t.Amount)
```